# Entity Framework removes files from Source Control

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, tfs, poco

we're using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 with Entity Framework 6.0.2.

Our process for adding new tables, and new pocos is described in these steps:

1. Define new tables in the database project.
2. Publish the database to localdb server
3. Open EDMX-Designer and right click somewhere in the designer and select "Update Model from Database..."
4. Save the EDMX

The Code-Generator re-creates all pocos under the edmx-name.tt file inside of the edmx-name.edmx container.

In most of the cases everything works fine! In some cases the code-generator removes certain files from the source control. Most of the files existed already before the "Update from Database..." process, and were already under source control. I have to right-click the edmx-name.tt file and select "Add files to source control" to fix this.

This is a nightmare for the development process in the team! If it would happen always, I would always check the pocos by myself before checking in. But it is totally random, I can not see a reason why this is happening.

Is anyone experiencing problems like that? How can we fix that?

(I have had problems like that with other Versions of EF, too)

Comment: Do you modify your model (database) between the POCOs regenerations?

Comment: @Peter that is possible, but only before our first deploy in a productive environment, which is going to happen soon. Is that the reason?

Comment: Just had this exact problem occur.  Update the entity model from the database due to changes, and it removed a number of existing entity files from source control.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have generated files under source control. If you remove them, but keep your entity model, them this will not be an issue.

Comment: This is not how the code generation works for entity framework.  The EDMX file generates files at design time, which are checked in and out of source control for you.